# Connection string error using membership provider from WCF service 

Tags: asp.net, wcf, membership-provider

The target is: I need a wcf method which will create user in the database.

I am using membership provider. and My client is SmartPhone/mobile device.

I wrote a method which will create user BUT when I test the method I get the following error.

**error:**

**An error occurred while attempting to initialize a System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection object. The value that was provided for the connection string may be wrong, or it may contain an invalid syntax.
Parameter name: connectionString**

And I get this error in the following line:

```
Membership.CreateUser(name, password,email,"question","answer",true,out createStatus);
```

I am using the same connectionString that I use to read data from the database.

My connection string is:

```
<add name="MajangoEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/EntityModel.MajangoEntityModel.csdl|res://*/EntityModel.MajangoEntityModel.ssdl|res://*/EntityModel.MajangoEntityModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=tcp:sql2k298.discountasp.net;initial catalog=SQL2008R2_835021_myddb;user id=SQL2008R2_835021_mydb_user;password=mypassword;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Can anybody help me with some ideas??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That connection string includes some Entity Framework specific data. Try instead just the "provider connection string" embedded within it:

```
 <add name="MajangoEntities" connectionString="data source=tcp:sql2k298.discountasp.net;initial catalog=SQL2008R2_835021_myddb;user id=SQL2008R2_835021_mydb_user;password=mypassword;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework">
```

The rest of the data in there (the metadata, etc.) is just confusing SQL Server.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the answer. I did what you've suggested. Now I get another error. Error: "The specified named connection is either not found in the configuration, not intended to be used with the EntityClient provider, or not valid." And it comes from the entitymodel.designer file.

Comment: Ah, OK - you'll need two connection strings, then. Try duplicating this line, next to the existing "MajangoEntities" string, but with a different name. Then, in your `<membership>` section make sure the provider references the name of this new connection string in the `connectionStringName` attribute.

Comment: That solves the problem. :) But Is it a good idea to use two connectionString? if you can describe a little about why the first connectionstring is not good enough, will be a great help.

Comment: Hurrah. EF has its own connection string format, as you've found.