# How to solve the error occurred in password recovery?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I'm using asp.net c# with EF and i'm trying to reset the password when user forget it. And in there i'm sending an email link to the user's provided email if it is in the database.

But it'll give me an error at the point **member = Membership.GetUser(foundemail);** saying

> {"An error occurred while attempting to initialize a System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection object. The value that was provided for the connection string may be wrong, or it may contain an invalid syntax.\r\nParameter name: connectionString"}

Here is my code in the controller

```
[HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult ResetPassword(ResetPasswordModel resetpasswordmodel)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //User user;
            MembershipUser member;
            using (TheFoodyContext db = new TheFoodyContext())
            {
                /*var foundemail = (from e in db.Users
                                     where e.email == resetpasswordmodel.Email
                                     select e.email).FirstOrDefault();*/

                var foundemail = (db.Users.Find(resetpasswordmodel.Email)).email.ToString();

                if (foundemail != null)
                {

                    member = Membership.GetUser(foundemail);    
                }
                else
                {
                    member = null;
                }
            }

            if (member != null)
            {
                //Generate password token that will be used in the email link to authenticate user
                var token = WebSecurity.GeneratePasswordResetToken(member.Email);
                // Generate the html link sent via email
                string resetLink = "<a href='"
                   + Url.Action("ResetPasswordView", "Account", new { rt = token }, "http")
                   + "'>Reset Password Link</a>";
                // Email stuff
                string subject = "Reset your password for TheFoody.com";
                string body = "You link: " + resetLink;
                string from = "abcd123@gmail.com";
                string to = resetpasswordmodel.Email;

                System.Net.Mail.MailMessage message = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage(from, to);
                message.Subject = subject;
                message.Body = body;
                SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();

                // Attempt to send the email
                try
                {
                    client.Send(message);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Issue sending email: " + e.Message);
                }
            }
            else // Email not found
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "No user found by that email.");
            }
        }
        return View(resetpasswordmodel);
    }
```

And here is my connectionString in web.config

```
<add name="TheFoodyContext" connectionString="metadata=res://*/TheFoodyModel.csdl|res://*/TheFoodyModel.ssdl|res://*/TheFoodyModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=DESKTOP-NJOQTOK;initial catalog=TheFoody;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

I'm very new to this environment and can anyone help me?

Comment: The connection string doesn't look right. Try moving data source=DESKTOP-NJOQTOK;initial catalog=TheFoody;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework into its own entry.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8122361/861716